# Change color of an ion-item on condition

Tags: ionic-framework, colors

I would like to change color of my ion-item based on some condition. (Making an ion-item non-clickable or non-editable). Have added the code to make it non-clickable ,however the color of the text is still blue color which will confuse user to click on it.

Have tried using the ternary operator but that was not working.

```
<ion-item color="light" (click)="!isShipButtonDisabled && navigateBack()">
  <p>Transfer Orders</p>
  <ion-note item-end color="!isShipButtonDisabled ? 'primary' : 'secondary'">
    {{transferOrderCount}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

Any help would be hugely helpful!

Comment: your can use ngStyle attribute to change css. e.g `[ngClass]="{'textColor': condition == true, 'textColorChange': condition !== true }"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color will change based on your variable if you add square brackets around color.

```
<ion-note item-end [color]="!isShipButtonDisabled ? 'primary' : 'secondary'">
```

Adding the square brackets will tell angular to evaluate that expression.

Comment: thanks that worked!. Though it is not giving the 'primary' color which is supposed to be blue!.It is defaulting there to grey!

Comment: @Nth-Tester ensure that the primary color is indeed blue (which it will be if you haven't changed it) and that there's no spelling errors. If all that's good, inspect the text once the app is running using Chrome Debug and see if the `ion-note` element has the .ion-color-primary class (or secondary) associated with it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I overlooked the primary part. it was overridden in variables.scss